# Is there a name for the class of functions that don't depend on argument order?

Tags: functions, terminology

To provide examples of such functions:

$$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$$

$$f(x,y)=f(y,x)=x^y+y^x$$

In contrast, here are examples of functions that **do depend** on the argument order:

$$f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i x_i$$

$$f(x,y)=x^y+y$$

Is there a name for the former class of functions?

---

*P.S. Commutativity is defined for operations, not sure if that's a correct term for multivariate functions over more than 2 arguments.*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Often the term is *symmetric functions*.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_function

Comment: I'd just note that in some contexts this might be unclear; it could also mean the function is invariant under e.g. a translation on the arguments.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Can you give an example? I have never seen "symmetric function" used for any other kind of invariance.

Comment: @MishaLavrov perhaps it's more of a physics than maths thing. You might hear things like "the Coulomb potential is symmetric", meaning invariant under spatial rotations.

Comment: Ah! No, even in math the *adjective* "symmetric" would be ambiguous. But saying that something *is a symmetric function* can only mean to me (and, I suspect, to most mathematicians).